# SettingWithCopyWarning happens on DataFrame.astype unreasonably

Tags: python, pandas

This is very strange and annoying: I have a python script which contains below DataFrame:

```
>>> x_pattern
sim_target_id line_on_trench    top     bot orientation session_id
            4              0  sim_1  sim_10   X_overlay          1
           64              0  sim_8  sim_31   X_overlay          1
```

If I try:

```
>>> x_pattern['sim_target_id'] = x_pattern['sim_target_id'].astype(int)
```

A familiar warning will raise:

```
86: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
x_pattern['sim_target_id'] = x_pattern['sim_target_id'].astype(int)
```

However, if I insert below lines into my script:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],'value': [1, 2, 3],'ccc':['a','vb','c']})
df1.value = df1.value.astype('int')
```

No 'SettingWithCopyWarning' will be raised on the df1 operations!

I tried the recommend .loc method - does not work, I tried to astype inplace - does not work. Could someone help me?

Appendix - How is the DataFrame created:
The DataFrame is created from a sqlite database:

```
sqlite_path = 'xxx'

engine2 = create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(sqlite_path))
connection2 = engine2.connect()

resoverall = connection2.execute("SELECT \ 
             sim_target_id,line_on_trench,top,bot,orientation,session_id \
                                FROM \
                                sim_targets \
                                WHERE \
                                sim_target_id In ({});".format(','.join(selected_id))) #pattern info
sim_targets = pd.DataFrame(resoverall.fetchall())
sim_targets.columns = resoverall.keys()
print sim_targets.dtypes
x_pattern = sim_targets[(sim_targets['orientation']=='X_overlay')&(sim_targets['sim_target_id'].isin(x_sim_id))]
print x_pattern
x_pattern['sim_target_id'] = x_pattern['sim_target_id'].astype(int)
```

The output will be:

```
sim_target_id     object
line_on_trench    object
top               object
bot               object
orientation       object
session_id        object
dtype: object
  sim_target_id line_on_trench    top     bot orientation session_id
0             4              0  sim_1  sim_10   X_overlay          1
1            64              0  sim_8  sim_31   X_overlay          1
test.py:37: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  x_pattern['sim_target_id'] = x_pattern['sim_target_id'].astype(int)
```

I just tried to manually input the DataFrame and the warning won't appear. But I can't tell the difference between the manual df and imported df, they look just the same - value and dtypes.

Comment: Provide a reproducible example, like how's `x_pattern` has been generated. Also, mention the code to reproduce the codes for others.

Comment: @meW, please help check my code. The problem looks more weird now

Comment: That's because you are modifying a copy. Use `x_pattern = sim_targets[(sim_targets['orientation']=='X_overlay')&(sim_targets['sim_target_id'].isin(x_sim_id))].copy()`.

Comment: @jpp, great thanks!! Correct me if I'm wrong: .copy() clearly tells compiler that this is a copy, so the warning won't show up. But with or without .copy() actually doesn't change the way of working of my code, anyway x_pattern is a copy of the slice from sim_targets, right?

Comment: @ShiangHoo, It makes a big difference. Without `.copy` your code is ambiguous (whether or not it works). With `.copy` it's clear and  explicit and *guarantees* there's no link between `x_pattern` and `sim_targets`. If assignments works, it's an *implementation detail* you shouldn't rely on.

Comment: @jpp, thanks for the explanation. You are right, I shouldn't rely on the compiler to understand the ambiguous part.